# Hide/show gridview column when a menu item is checked or unchecked

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I want to hide a grid view column when a menu-item is clicked.

Xaml:

```
    <MenuItem Header="View">
                    <MenuItem Header="Columns" Name="menuView" ItemsSource="{Binding Path= MyMenuItems}">
                        <MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
                                <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Header}" />
                                <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="{Binding IsChecked,Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                                <Setter Property="IsCheckable" Value="{Binding IsCheckable}"/>
                                <Setter Property="Icon" Value= "{Binding ImageIcon}"/>
                                <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value= "{Binding Path =IsEnabled}"/>
                                <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Path=  MyMenuItems}"/>
                                <Setter Property= "Command" Value= "{Binding DataContext.CheckedViewMenuItemsCmd, RelativeSource ={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type MenuItem}}}"/>
                                <Setter Property="CommandParameter" Value="{Binding}" />
                                <Setter Property="StaysOpenOnClick" Value="{Binding StaysOpenOnClick}"/>
                            </Style>                            </MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>                          
                    </MenuItem>

    <ListView Name="MyListView" Grid.Row="1"  SelectedItem ="{Binding SelectedFeature}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path= MyListItems}">
                <ListView.View>
                    <GridView util:GridViewColumnClass.HeaderTextMember="HeaderText"
                              util:GridViewColumnClass.DisplayMemberMember="DisplayMember"
                              util:GridViewColumnClass.ColumnsSource=" {Binding Columns}"/>
   </ListView.View>
```

The menu items header is the same as Grid view column header . When a menu item is checked or unchecked, I would like the grid view column to be shown or hidden.

I do have a GidViewColumnVisibilityManager similar to this one here .
[WPF: How to hide GridViewColumn using XAML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/729866/wpf-how-to-hide-gridviewcolumn-using-xaml)

ViewModel:

```
    public MyViewModel()
    {
        MyListItems = SomeClass.instance.messages;
        _MenuItems = new ObservableCollection<MenuClass>();
        //populates the view menu
        PopulateViewMenu();

        this.Columns = new ObservableCollection<ColumnDescriptor>
        {

            new ColumnDescriptor{ Width = 40, HeaderText ="column1",  DisplayMember= "column1"},
            new ColumnDescriptor{ Width = 40, HeaderText="column2" ,  DisplayMember= "column2"},
            new ColumnDescriptor{ Width = 70, HeaderText="column3" , DisplayMember="column3"},

        };

        //event to command 
        CheckedViewMenuItemsCmd = new RelayCommand<MenuClass>(CheckedViewMenuItems);
    }
     public ObservableCollection<ColumnDescriptor> Columns { get; private set; }

    private ICommand _addColumnCommand;

    public ICommand AddColumnCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (_addColumnCommand == null)
            {
                _addColumnCommand = new RelayCommand<string>(
                    s =>
                    {
                        this.Columns.Add(new ColumnDescriptor { HeaderText = s, DisplayMember = s });
                    });
            }
            return _addColumnCommand;
        }
    }

    private ICommand _removeColumnCommand;
    public ICommand RemoveColumnCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (_removeColumnCommand == null)
            {
                _removeColumnCommand = new RelayCommand<string>(
                    s =>
                    {
                        this.Columns.Remove(this.Columns.FirstOrDefault(d => d.DisplayMember == s));
                    });
            }
            return _removeColumnCommand;
        }
    }
     private void CheckedViewMenuItems(MenuClass m)
    {
        try
        {
            bool IsChecked = m.IsChecked;
            if (IsChecked)
            {

                ColumnDescriptor cl1 =     new ColumnDescriptor{ Width = 40, HeaderText =m.Header,  DisplayMember= "Revision"};
                int idx = Convert.ToInt32(m.Tag);
                int insertidx = Math.Min(idx, this.Columns.Count);
                this.Columns.Insert(insertidx, cl1);
            }
            else
            {
                foreach (var item in this.Columns)
                {
                    if (item.HeaderText == m.Header)
                    {
                       // item.DisplayMember = "";
                        this.Columns.Remove(item);                            

                        break;
                    }

                }
            }


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}{1}{2}{1}{3}", ex.GetType().ToString(), Environment.NewLine, ex.Message, ex.StackTrace));

        }

    }
```

I am a bit confused about how to use the booleon to visible converter and implement the functionality. Your help is appreciated. Please ask me questions if you have any. Thank you folks.
 I tried insert and remove instead of show and hide, the Remove works like a charm but the insert needs a display member binding to bind to the collection every time which is obvious. I tried for one column, it works fine, i need it to work for all. Any thoughts?

Comment: Thank you... Yes they should not have Tags. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround. I have a new function GetdisplayMember which returns a string, depending on which menuitem was clicked. Here is workaround. Works nicely. Cheers!

```
 private string GetDisplayMember(int tag)
    {
        string displayMember = string.Empty;
        if (tag != null)
        {
            switch (tag)
            {
                case 0:
                    displayMember = "Revision";
                    break;
                case 1:
                    displayMember = "Class";
                    break;
                case 2:
                    displayMember = "Errordate";
                    break;
         }

      }

        return displayMember;
    }

    private void CheckedViewMenuItems(MenuClass m)
    {
        try
        {    
            if (m!=null)
            {

                bool IsChecked = m.IsChecked;
                if (IsChecked)
                {                    
                   ColumnDescriptor cl1 =new   ColumnDescriptor     
                    {           

                       HeaderText =m.Header, 
                       DisplayMember= GetDisplayMember(m.Tag)
                     };
                       int idx = Convert.ToInt32(m.Tag);
                       int insertidx = Math.Min(idx,   
                       this.Columns.Count);
                       this.Columns.Insert(insertidx, cl1);
                }
                else
                {
                    foreach (var item in this.Columns)
                    {
                        if (item.HeaderText == m.Header)
                        {
                           // item.DisplayMember = "";
                            this.Columns.Remove(item);  
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }            

            }              
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}{1}{2}{1}{3}", ex.GetType().ToString(), Environment.NewLine, ex.Message, ex.StackTrace));
            ErrorLogger.Log(LogLevel.Error, ex.ToString());
        }
```