# Changing a GridViewColumn based on Binding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a binding `ShowingRecentDocuments` that returns a boolean value. Based on this boolean value I would like to show one of two columns in a GridView:

```
      <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ModelItems, Mode=OneWay}">
        <ListView.View>
          <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Templates" 
                            DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding PrettyName}" />

            //If ShowingRecentDocuments == true, show this column
            <GridViewColumn Header="Last Modified" 
                            DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding TimeModified}"/>

            //else show this column
            <GridViewColumn Header="Last Opened"
                            DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding LastOpened}"/>
          </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
      </ListView>
```

I can't seem to use a `DataTrigger` within a `GridViewColumn`, but instead only within `GridViewColumn.CellTemplate`. How could I go about changing the visibility (or equivalent) of the columns for this task?

Comment: there is a qustion (with answers) about changing visibility. another solution is making   static prop `ShowingRecentDocuments` in Model, making static prop `OpenedOrModifiedHeader => ShowingRecentDocuments ? "Last Modified" : "Last Opened"` making readonly prop `OpenedOrModified => ShowingRecentDocuments ?  TimeModified : LastOpened` bind `OpenedOrModifiedHeader`  to `Header` and `OpenedOrModified` to `DisplayMemberBinding`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two options.

1. You can define to ListViews with the same data and manipulating their visibility. This would mean you have always 2 ListViews in the view which is ugly and cost performance.
2. You can adapter [these answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9634769/1015350) and define an attacked property that manage the visibility of the columns.

I would prefer the second one.